# Thesaurus file (or plugin for online thesaurus tools) for non-English languages

Tags: thesaurus

I found a lot of plugins (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33453468/vim-thesaurus-file/35680469#35680469) for example) and sources for English, but almost nothing for Russian (and other languages).

Are there good source of thesaurus (or plugin for online tools) for non-English languages?

Comment: You have any online source for Russian synonym, like a website or something? I can easily write a backend with its API for my existing query plugin.   https://github.com/Ron89/thesaurus_query.vim

Comment: @Chong, thanks! I've done superficial research and havn't find one, but I'll try again!

Comment: Found one. http://www.jiport.com/ But connection from my location is not ideal. I don't understand Russian, so I can't really tell. You think this one good enough?

Comment: @Chong, I answered in issue. It is not useless, but certainly not perfect. But I'm very grateful anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I have added Russian Language support for my Plugin:

https://github.com/Ron89/thesaurus_query.vim

To activate it, add the following line to your `~/.vimrc` file after installing:

```
let g:tq_language=['ru','en']
```

Or if you don't want to use English thesaurus query at all, remove 'en' from the example above.

Russian synonym is queried from website [jeck.ru](http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/). Since this feature is just implemented and I am no Russian speaker. There might still be bugs/unexpected behaviour. Please send me feedback on Github if you find any while using.

---

**Update**

The plugin now support German (with woxikon.de), Russian (with jeck.ru) and Chinese (with cilin.txt) thesaurus query.